# How to handler errors/exceptions while using Spring Kafka framework?

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am not able to find how to do custom error handling in for a spring kafka consumer.

My requirement is:

1. For any deserialization errors, just write the error and message to database.
2. For any errors in execution under `@KafkaListener` method, retry 3 times and then write the error and message to database.

From the spring docs, I found that,
For 1, I will have to use `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` and it will then call the @KafkaListener error handler.
For 2, framework provides `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which handles message retries.

I am not understanding where can I add the code to write the exception/message to database in addition to enable configured retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a recoverer to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`

```
new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> {
    Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof DeserializationException) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }, new FixedBackOff(2000L, 2L));
```

By default, deserialization exceptions are not retried; most others are retried before calling the recoverer.

Comment: Here I am not getting DeserializationException, It is wrapped in ListenerExecutionFailedException. I have to first cast the exception to ListenerExecutionFailedException and then check if it contains DeserializationException or other type.

Comment: Sorry, yes; but you don't really have to cast it; all `Throwable`s have `cause()`.